# C# Get Process API Usage

Tags: c#

Is there a method to detect what APIs are being called? Say I wanted to detect any application that uses the ReadProcessMemory API for instance. How doable is this in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) to hook system function calls and record them in a database of some sort. It's not for the faint of heart, however, and you need to be *very* performance conscious (because it's all too easy to bring a system to it's knees if you end up hooking the wrong thing, or take too long in your hook procedure, etc).

What do you need this for? I would say that there might be a better way to do what you're trying to do...

Comment: We're writing a small anti-cheat application for an old dying game. We want to hook the games process and monitor certain api calls. ReadProcessMemory & WriteProcessMemory are our main concerns. Before the game is launched we'd like to scan each active process for these calls. So Hook before game, then unhook. Then we have an event driven method that detects new processes. Each new process should be checked for these api usages.

Thanks.